# Is it possible to encrypt a private_key with a public_key?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I've got the following code:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa

generated_private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537, key_size=2048, backend=default_backend()
)
bytes_private_key = generated_private_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption(),
)

generated_public_key = generated_private_key.public_key()
bytes_public_key = generated_public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
)

object_public_key: rsa.RSAPublicKey = serialization.load_pem_public_key(  # type: ignore
    bytes_public_key, backend=default_backend()
)

# Error happens in the following block:
enc_key = object_public_key.encrypt(  # <-- Why do I get an error here?
    bytes_private_key,  # <-- How can I encrypt this key with another public_key?
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None,
    ),
)
```

*This code should run as is, as long as cryptography is installed.*

The Error happens in the last block when I try to encrypt the created private_key. The last block throws: `ValueError: Encryption/decryption failed.`.

The error might be related to the length of the keys and that I can only encrypt data that is shorter than the public_key. However, I'm not sure if that is the problem here. How can I encrypt a private_key with another public_key?

```
Note: In this example I encrypt the private_key with its own public_key, but that is just to simplify this example. In the real code I use another public_key.
```

Comment: "Is it possible to encrypt a private_key with a public_key?"  Yes, it is possible, but why you want to do that? Private keys as their name suggest are meant to be private and not shared with anybody.

Comment: To be able to store them inside a database. For example there is 1 private key for a user and that key stays with the user forever. But then there are private_keys for shared objects and those private_keys should be encrypted with each user's private_key.

Comment: Another example is a hierarchical folder structure. In which you can get access to a parent folder and then you have access to all the child folders, because the parent folder can decrypt the child folder's encrypted private_key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, simply because you can encrypt any data. However, just as with longer messages, it makes most sense to use hybrid cryptography here: encrypt with a random symmetric data key such as an AES key, and then encrypt the AES key with the private key. As you are using a random key you can use an all zero IV and then encrypt in any secure mode, e.g. CBC or CTR mode. You can use GCM mode or another AEAD mode to add some message integrity (not authenticity as anybody can encrypt with a public key).

Using a larger encryption key is also possible but more ugly and it will generate a larger ciphertext than using hybrid mode. You should probably use some 19 bytes of overhead for RSA / PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. It has a minimum of 11 bytes of padding, but then the random component is only 8 random bytes and you'd need 16 for added security. For the more modern / secure OAEP padding have a look at my answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100/1172).

Comment: I see, seems like hybrid is the way to go. There is no way around the additional complexity with hybrid right? Because the private_key I want to encrypt has a length of 1675.

Comment: The complexity of generating a secure random key and then encrypting with it? No, not really. 1675 bits for the private key (modulus?) is a very weird size, not sure what that means. Or are we talking about bytes of the encoded key?

Comment: Sorry for the additional comment and stuff, I'm experiencing network errors, possibly due to the company VPN software.

Comment: 1675 is the bytes length of the private key. Basically a private_key str encoded with utf-8 and then the len(bytes_key) == 1675. bytes_key looks kinda like this b"---Begin Key --- ...numbers and letters... --- End Key ---". And the private key in the example is a lot longer than the public key.

Comment: That's a PEM encoded private key. It usually reads RSA PRIVATE KEY or PRIVATE KEY, depending if it is PKCS#1 encoded or PKCS#8 encoded respectively. It's a bit of a shame to encrypt that, as the binary key it encodes is a lot smaller. It usually is relatively big - even as binary bytes - because it contains the components required to perform modular exponentiation using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the CRT parameters.